# Triangle of "T" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT ** I can't multiply strings by an integer. Its for a homework and those were the instructions **

I need to do a triangle in python using for loops or while loops(mandatory). The final output should look like this.

```
T
TT
TTT
TTTT
TTTTT
TTTTTT
TTTTT
TTTT
TTT
TT
T
```

I already figure the firs part, that prints from the first line to the middle line, but i cant figure how to reverse my function.

```
def triangle(base):
    for length in range(base+1):
        for b in range(length):
            print("T",end="")
    print()
```

What I tried to do was sustracting length like this.

```
def triangle(base):
for length in range(base+1):
    for b in range(length):
        print("T",end="")
    print()
for length in range(base):
    for b in range(length-1):
        print("T",end="")
print()
```

But only print this and I cant find the way to keep printing the "T" until it gets done:

```
T
TT
TTT
TTTT
TTTTT
TTTTTT
TTTTT
```

Comment: You can make `range()` go backwards. (Something like `range(base, 0, -1)` should work, give or take an off-by-one error.)

Comment: Are the first half and the second half similar?  How are they different? You made a loop to construct the first half.  Can you make a loop to construct the second half?  What arguments does range() take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
def triangle(base):
    for i in range(1,base+1):
        print(''.join('T' for o in range(i)))
    for i in reversed(range(1,base)  # note the lack of the +1 on base
        print(''.join('T' for o in range(i)))
```

#### Example

```
from shapes import triangle
triangle(3)
```

> ```
> T
> TT
> TTT
> TT
> T
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a single list comprehension:

```
t = 6
['T' * (n if n < t else 2*t-n) for n in range(1,2*t)]
```

It's simple to turn this into a single for loop:

```
t = 6
for n in range(1,2*t):
    print('T'*(n if n < t else 2*t-n))
```

Corrected for changes in the question:

```
[''.join('T' for _ in range(n if n < t else 2*t-n)) for n in range(1,2*t)]
----
for n in range(1,2*t):
    print(''.join('T' for _ in range(n if n < t else 2*t-n))
```

Comment: You should check this in question "I can't multiply strings by an integer. Its for a homework and those were the instructions".

Comment: @Drake, that was added after my solution!! The `''.join()` posted in another solution would solve that problem.

Comment: this is a very elegant solution none the less!

Answer (score 0):

```
def triangle(base):
    T=''
    for i in range(n):
        Ts = Ts + 'T'
        print Ts
    for i in range(n-1):
        Ts = Ts[1:]
        print Ts

>>> pt(6)
T
TT
TTT
TTTT
TTTTT
TTTTTT
TTTTT
TTTT
TTT
TT
T
```