# Triangle of odd numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a triangle of number like this one here

```
1
12
123
12
1
```

Number of line is chosen by the user. For example if user enters : 5. There must be 5 line (like in the previous triangle). And the number must be an odd number.

Here is what I have done so far but i'm stuck.

```
oddNumber = int(input("Enter an odd number here:"))

for i in range(oddNumber):
    for j in range(oddNumber):
        print("", end="")

    for k in range(1,i):
        print(k, end="")

    print("")
```

The output of that is (if I enter 5):

```
1
12
123
```

Comment: Yet another triangle question. There are [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312616/how-to-make-a-number-triangle), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641031/print-triangle-of-numbers-in-python), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735101/triangle-of-numbers-on-python), ...etc, etc.

Comment: Right now, you're generating numbers (x) that are `1<=x<i`. Which for this `i` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triangle of "T" in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439852/triangle-of-t-in-python)

Comment: ok but how do you do with number?
1
12
1